# Generic double linkled list using smart pointers

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

I am trying to implement a generic double linked list using smart pointers. At the moment I am trying to write a push_back function but I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LinkedList, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(155): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2309): note: could be 'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2247): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2173): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(155): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>>, DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(153): note: while compiling class template member function 'void DoubleLinkedList<int>::push_back(T &&)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\main.cpp(97): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void DoubleLinkedList<int>::push_back(T &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\main.cpp(96): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'DoubleLinkedList<int>' being compiled
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(159): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2309): note: could be 'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2247): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2173): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(159): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>>, DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(163): error C2065: 'newnode': undeclared identifier
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(164): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2309): note: could be 'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2247): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &&) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory(2173): note: or       'std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(std::nullptr_t) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\linkedlist\linkedlist\doublelinkedlist.h(164): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::unique_ptr<DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node,std::default_delete<_Ty>>, DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=DoubleLinkedList<int>::Node
1>        ]
1>Done building project "LinkedList.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the function I am trying to implement:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::push_back(T &&thedata) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(std::move(thedata));
    newNode->previous = std::move(tail.get());

    if (!head) {
        head = std::move(newNode);
        tail = head.get();
    }

    else {
        tail->next = std::move(newnode);
        tail = tail->next.get();
    }
}
```

The error occurs at `newNode->previous = std::move(tail.get());` and at `tail = tail->next.get();`. I do not know how to fix this issue to make sure I am making the correct links I need for a double linked list.

This what the class where I initialize tail and head looks like:

```
class DoubleLinkedList {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> previous = nullptr;

    };
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> tail = nullptr;
};
```

Here is when I try to use the push_back function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <ostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedList.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     ///////////////////////////// Double Linked List //////////////////////
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     DoubleLinkedList<int> obj;
     obj.push_back(2);
     obj.push_back(4);
     obj.push_back(6);
     obj.push_back(8);
     obj.push_back(10);
     std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
     std::cout<<"---------------displaying all nodes---------------";
     std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
     std::cout << obj << "\n";


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You have too many `std::unique_ptr`. Use shared ownership, or use pointer for `prev`/`tail`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reiterated by Jarod42 use shared_ptr and make struct node accessible. Try this:

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    Node(T val):data(val){}
    T data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next = nullptr;
    std::weak_ptr<Node> previous ; //weak_ptr to avoid cyclic reference

};

template <class T>
class DoubleLinkedList {
public:
    void push_back(T thedata);

    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> head = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> tail = nullptr;
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, DoubleLinkedList<T>& obj) {
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> node = obj.head;
    while (node!= nullptr) {
        os << node->data << std::endl;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return os;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedList<T>::push_back(T thedata) {
    std::shared_ptr<Node<T>> newNode = std::make_shared<Node<T>>(thedata);
    newNode->previous = tail;

    if (!head) {
        head = newNode;
        tail = head;
    }

    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    DoubleLinkedList<int> obj;
    obj.push_back(2);
    obj.push_back(4);
    obj.push_back(6);
    obj.push_back(8);
    obj.push_back(10);
    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "---------------displaying all nodes---------------";
    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << "\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A doubly-linked list is not a good candidate for smart pointers (at least for the internal front/back links) due to the cycles.  Nodes don't own each other, and because there's not an ownership or hierarchical relationship, there's no way for reference counts or similar to decrement such that the memory can be reclaimed when the list is no longer needed.

However, you could conceivably use owning pointers (unique or shared) for links in one direction and weak_ptrs in the other direction to avoid those problems.  That would establish a clear parent/child relationship and allow memory management to work correctly.

Having said all that, clients of the list certainly might want to use smart pointers to hold the items they insert into the list.  I just wouldn't use them in the list internals.

Comment: You could do that but it isn't the purpose of `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @curiousguy:  Agreed--I said you could do it, but in the end I wouldn't.